# If $f$ is a non constant entire function which is real on the real axis then $\arg f(\overline{z})=-\arg f(z) $

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, multivalued-functions

> If $f$ is a non constant entire function which is real on the real axis then prove that $$\arg f(\overline{z})=-\arg f(z) $$
> where $z=x+iY$, $0<x<1$ and $f$ is non zero on the horizontal line segment $z=x+iY$, $0<x<1$.

By Schwarz reflection principle we have $$\arg f(\overline{z})=\arg \overline{f(z)} $$
Since $\arg$ is a multivalued function, so after this I am stuck. Please solve the question.

Comment: Hint: $\arg f(\overline z) + \arg f(z)$ is a continuous function (away from the zeros of $f$). How does it relate to $\arg\bigl( \overline{f(z)} f(z) \bigr)$?

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks. Sorry I can't see the relation. Can you please write as a detailed answer. I will most humbly accept it

Comment: Hint: $\overline{f(\overline z)}$ is an entire function, which coincides with $f$ on the real line.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks, but then how is this result given by you useful?

Comment: @GregMartin Is $\arg (\overline{f(z)}f(z))=\arg f(z)+\arg\overline{f(z)}$? But $\arg$ is multivalued. Can we have the above equality?

Comment: I'm not sure what the whole $0<x<1$ is all about.

Comment: How is it useful? Okay, here is the next hint: $\overline{f(\overline z)} = f(z)$ for all $z$.

Comment: @zhoraster I am sorry. I still can't understand. Please write an answer, I will respectfully accept it

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: @zhoraster Sorry, I can't understand. argument is a multivalued function. How to deal with that?

Comment: So what does the equality $\arg y_1= - \arg y_2$ mean, in your opinion?

Comment: @zhoraster $\arg (xy)=\arg x+\arg y$ holds for $x,y$ real

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is real on the real axis then the $a_n
$ are real in the power series expansion.

Hence $\operatorname{im} f(\overline{z}) = \sum_n a_n \operatorname{im} \overline{z}^n = \sum_n a_n \operatorname{im} \overline{z^n} = \sum_n a_n (-\operatorname{im} z^n ) = - \operatorname{im} f(z) $ and similarly
$\operatorname{re} f(\overline{z}) =  \operatorname{re} f(z) $.

Comment: Thanks. But in the question we have to prove about argument.?

Comment: I know that $\arg f(z)=\Im \log f(z)$

Comment: So by your answer we get $\arg f(\overline{z})=\arg (Re f(z)-i Im f(z))$. What to do after this?

Comment: Assuming that by $\operatorname{arg} z$ you mean $\{ \theta \mid z = |z|e^{i \theta} \}$ then the result is immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment &zhoraster fis real on real line so $\bar {f(\bar z)}=f(\bar z)$
Let $f(z)=u+iv, u,v \in \Re \implies Arg(f( z())= Arg(u+iv)=\tan^{-1} v/u$.
Then
$Arg(f(\bar z))=Arg(u-iv)=\tan^{-1} (-v/u)=-\tan^{-1} (v/u)=-Arg(f(z))$

Comment: But our arg is not the principal argument